# displaying a table without invalid values python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have the following data on the joint probabilities for two random variables:

```
N = 116
n = 25
q = 0.05
I = stats.binom(N,q)
D2 = [stats.hypergeom(N,K,n) for K in range(0,117)]
pmf_I = [I.pmf(i).round(4) for i in np.arange(0,117)]
conditional_pmf = [[D2[i].pmf(d).round(4) for d in np.arange(0,26)] for i in np.arange(0,117)]

joint_pmf_ID = [[(pmf_I[i] * conditional_pmf[i][d]).round(4) for d in np.arange(0,26)
                 if ((pmf_I[i] * conditional_pmf[i][d]).round(4))!= 0]
                for i in np.arange(0,117) if pmf_I[i] != 0]


for i in range(len(joint_pmf_ID)):
    for j in range(len(joint_pmf_ID[9])):
        if j == len(joint_pmf_ID[i]) - 1 and j != 6:
            joint_pmf_ID[i].append(0)
        else:
            continue

joint_pmf_ID

[[0.0026, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0.0125, 0.0034, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.0295, 0.0164, 0.0022, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.0462, 0.0389, 0.0104, 0.0009, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.0535, 0.0607, 0.0246, 0.0042, 0.0003, 0, 0],
 [0.0489, 0.0703, 0.0384, 0.0099, 0.0012, 0.0001, 0],
 [0.0369, 0.0644, 0.0444, 0.0155, 0.0029, 0.0003, 0],
 [0.0236, 0.0486, 0.0407, 0.0179, 0.0045, 0.0006, 0],
 [0.013, 0.0311, 0.0307, 0.0164, 0.0052, 0.001, 0.0001],
 [0.0063, 0.0172, 0.0196, 0.0124, 0.0048, 0.0011, 0.0002],
 [0.0027, 0.0083, 0.0108, 0.0079, 0.0036, 0.0011, 0.0002],
 [0.0011, 0.0036, 0.0053, 0.0044, 0.0023, 0.0008, 0.0002],
 [0.0004, 0.0014, 0.0023, 0.0021, 0.0013, 0.0005, 0.0001],
 [0.0001, 0.0005, 0.0009, 0.0009, 0.0006, 0.0003, 0.0001],
 [0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0001, 0, 0],
 [0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.0001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I've added in zeros so that I can display the data with looping functionality. Now Ideally I'd like to display only values that are above, say, 0.05, the rest being meaninglessly different from zero. The only way I have been able to do this is in the following extremely piece meal bit of code:

```
print("Joint probability distribution:")
print('|\t|',end='')
for y in range(len(values_D) - 1):
    print(f' D={y}\t|', end='')
print()
for i in range(len(values_I) - 3):
    print(f'| I={i}\t|', end='')
    for j in range(len(values_D) - 1):
        print(f'{joint_pmf_ID[i][j]:.3f}\t|', end='')
    print()
print()
```

Is there a better way to do this? It's hard because my initial data was a ragged list, so I had to just add zeros, and now it's all very awkward.

**EDIT**

I've updated my pmf list to get rid of the values from the beginning:

```
joint_pmf_ID = [[(pmf_I[i] * conditional_pmf[i][d]).round(4) for d in np.arange(0,26)
                 if ((pmf_I[i] * conditional_pmf[i][d]).round(4)) >= 0.005]
                for i in np.arange(0,117) if pmf_I[i] != 0]
```

Which gets me this:

```
[[0.0125, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.0295, 0.0164, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.0462, 0.0389, 0.0104, 0, 0],
 [0.0535, 0.0607, 0.0246, 0, 0],
 [0.0489, 0.0703, 0.0384, 0.0099, 0],
 [0.0369, 0.0644, 0.0444, 0.0155, 0],
 [0.0236, 0.0486, 0.0407, 0.0179, 0],
 [0.013, 0.0311, 0.0307, 0.0164, 0.0052, 0],
 [0.0063, 0.0172, 0.0196, 0.0124, 0, 0],
 [0.0083, 0.0108, 0.0079, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.0053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now I just need to display it! I've managed it with the following – again, very piecemeal – functionality:

```
values_I = np.arange(len(joint_pmf_ID))
values_D = np.arange(len(joint_pmf_ID[7]))
print("Joint probability distribution:")
print('|\t|',end='')
for y in range(len(values_D) - 1):
    print(f' D={y}\t|', end='')
print()
for i in range(len(values_I)):
    print(f'| I={i}\t|', end='')
    for j in range(len(values_D) - 1):
        print(f'{joint_pmf_ID[i][j]:.3f}\t|', end='')
    print()
print()


Joint probability distribution:
|   | D=0   | D=1   | D=2   | D=3   | D=4   |
| I=0   |0.013  |0.000  |0.000  |0.000  |0.000  |
| I=1   |0.029  |0.016  |0.000  |0.000  |0.000  |
| I=2   |0.046  |0.039  |0.010  |0.000  |0.000  |
| I=3   |0.053  |0.061  |0.025  |0.000  |0.000  |
| I=4   |0.049  |0.070  |0.038  |0.010  |0.000  |
| I=5   |0.037  |0.064  |0.044  |0.015  |0.000  |
| I=6   |0.024  |0.049  |0.041  |0.018  |0.000  |
| I=7   |0.013  |0.031  |0.031  |0.016  |0.005  |
| I=8   |0.006  |0.017  |0.020  |0.012  |0.000  |
| I=9   |0.008  |0.011  |0.008  |0.000  |0.000  |
| I=10  |0.005  |0.000  |0.000  |0.000  |0.000  |
```

Comment: Do you need to print it? Otherwise I'd suggest something like [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) see [Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-hist2d-in-python/)

Comment: The reason to print it was that I'd need a 3d visualisation to do it graphically, which was more effort than its worth compared to a table

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what format you're trying to do, but hope ths helps point you in the right direction.

If you want to print only the values where val > 0.05:

1. Make your `joint_pmf_ID` a numpy array.
2. Index by boolean condition and set the desired values to 0.
3. In your looping function, don't print zeros.

```
joint_pmf_ID = np.array(joint_pmf_ID)
joint_pmf_id[joint_pmf_id<=0.05] = 0
# Below is just a fancy print function; print how you will
for i, row in enumerate(joint_pmf_ID):
    print('| ')
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        print(val if val else ' ')
        print(' | ')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting. The main think I will have to adjust is for the nested lists in my joint_pmf variable